# .NET 8-Linux Docker Permission denied

Tags: .net, docker, jenkins

I did everything I could, searched all the topics on stackoverflow, but no matter what I did, it didn't work.
Please help me :)

I'm running my .net 8 project on docker with Jenkins
When I looked at the status of the container with portainer, I saw that it had entered the exit state and when I looked at its logs, I got the following error.
Error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmEKB.png)

Jenkins file:

```
   pipeline {
      agent any
      environment {
        DISABLE_AUTH = 'true'
        DB_ENGINE    = 'sqlite'
        DOTNET_CLI_HOME = "/tmp/DOTNET_CLI_HOME"
      }
      stages {
        stage("verify tooling") {
          steps {
            sh '''
              docker version
              docker info
              docker-compose version
            '''
          }
        }
        stage('Prune Docker data') {
          steps {
            sh 'docker system prune -a --volumes -f'
          }
        }
        stage('Start container') {
          steps {
            sh 'docker-compose down'
            sh 'docker-compose build'
            sh 'docker-compose up -d'
            sh 'docker-compose ps'
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

docker-compose file

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  blazorwebuitest:
    image: blazorwebuitest_ui
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: BlazorWebUI/Dockerfile
volumes:
  blazorwebdb_volume:
```

docker-compose.override.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  blazorwebuitest:
    container_name: blazorwebuitest_ui
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=TestL.31235
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp1.pfx
      - DatabaseSettings:ConnectionString=mongodb://blazorwebdb:27020
    ports:
      - "5040:80"
      - "5042:443"
    depends_on:
      - blazorwebdb
    volumes:
      - ./https/aspnetapp1.pfx:/https/aspnetapp1.pfx:ro
  blazorwebdb:
    container_name: blazorwebdb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27020:27017"
    volumes:
      - blazorwebdb_volume:/data/db
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-jammy AS base
USER root
WORKDIR /app
RUN chmod 777 -R /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-jammy AS build
RUN dotnet dev-certs https --clean
RUN dotnet dev-certs https
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["BlazorWebUI/BlazorWebUI.csproj", "BlazorWebUI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./BlazorWebUI/BlazorWebUI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/BlazorWebUI"
RUN dotnet build "./BlazorWebUI.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./BlazorWebUI.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BlazorWebUI.dll"]
```

Comment: You seem to have included a link of some sort in place of the error message.  Can you [edit] the question to include the actual text of the error in place of the link?  Do you have the same problem if you run the same containers without the Jenkins setup?